# Calculation of Jacobian, Hessian Matrices for Newton's Method with an Independent variable, x

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

Suppose I am trying to fit a non-linear function with parameters A, and B to some observed data:

$$f(x,A,B) = Ae^{(Bx)} $$

To the best of my understanding Jacobian matrix is a matrix containing the first derivative of each variable, in this case parameters A and B.

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 
\partial{f}/\partial{A} & \partial{f}/\partial{B}
\end{bmatrix} $$

However, I am not including the independent variable, x, in the Jacobian.

When performing gradient descent via Newton's Method for Optimisation, the formula for the updated values of A, and B is
:

$$ \mathbf{x}_{n+1} = \mathbf{x}_{n} -[\mathbf{H}f(x)]^{-1}\nabla f(x)  $$

Where $\mathbf{x}_{n}$,$\mathbf{x}_{n+1}$ contain the current and updated values for A and B for iteration $n$.

I am defining $\nabla f(x) $ as:
$$\nabla f(x) = -2J^{T}(Y-f(x,A,B))$$
Where Y is the observed data (X x 1 matrix), and $f(x,A,B)$ is the model with the current values of the parameters. $J$ is a (2 x obvs) matrix that includes the derivatives of $f$ with respect to A and B calculated at every point, $x$.

**My question is whether it is correct to calculate the derivative with respect to A, B at every point x for the Jacobian, J. If this is correct, then how do I calculate the Hessian matrix, $[\mathbf{H}f(x)]$? Do I instead include a derivative with respect to x, even though x will not change with each iteration, as it is an independent variable?**

Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the difference between a loss/objective function (usually denoted $L$) and the parameteric function $f$ you are fitting to.

A loss function measures the error of your fit. For example, you could take the loss function $L$ to be mean squared error:
$$
L(A,B)\equiv\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\left(f(x_{i};A,B)-y_{i}\right)^{2}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\left(Ae^{Bx_{i}}-y_{i}\right)^{2}.
$$
One way to find a local minimizer $(A,B)$ of $L$ is to solve $\nabla L(A,B)=0$.
This is where [Newton's method, a tool for finding roots of nonlinear systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Nonlinear_systems_of_equations), comes in handy.
In general, Newton's method applied to solve the equation $F(x)=0$ produces iterates
$$
x_{n+1}=x_{n}-[JF](x_{n})^{-1}F(x_{n})
$$
where $JF$ is the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $F$. Taking $F\equiv\nabla L$ in the above, we get
$$
(A_{n+1},B_{n+1})=(A_{n},B_{n})-\left([J\nabla L](A_{n},B_{n})\right)^{-1}\nabla L(A_{n},B_{n}).
$$
You should try to prove that $J\nabla L=HL$ where $HF$ is the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $F$.